# Unable to change TD background color using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-visualization

I have following snippet:

```
 function drawVisualization2(dataArray, divName) {
     var dataTbl = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);
     var table1 = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
         'chartType': 'Table',
         'containerId': 'chart3',
         dataTable: dataTbl,
         'options': {
             'width': '500px'
         }
     });
     table1.draw();

     function tableCleanUp() {
         google.visualization.events.addListener(table1.getChart(), 'sort', tableCleanUp2);
         tableCleanUp2();
     }

     function tableCleanUp2() {
         $('#chart3 .google-visualization-table-tr-odd, #chart3 .google-visualization-table-tr-even').each(function (e) {
             $(this).closest('td:nth-child(1)').css("background-color", "red");
         });
     }
     google.visualization.events.addListener(table1, 'ready', tableCleanUp);
 }
```

I am unable to change background color of a TD. My table looks like this

```
<div id="chart3" style="position: relative;">
    <div style="position: relative;">
        <div style="position: relative; overflow: auto; width: 500px;">
            <table class="google-visualization-table-table" cellspacing="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="google-visualization-table-tr-head">
                    <tr class="google-visualization-table-tr-even">
                    <tr class="google-visualization-table-tr-odd">
                        <td class="google-visualization-table-td">SPINAL FUSION EXCEPT CERVICAL W/O MCC</td>
                        <td class="google-visualization-table-td">1804860128.00</td>
                        <td class="google-visualization-table-td">6130083182.00</td>
                        <td class="google-visualization-table-td">70.56</td>
                        <td class="google-visualization-table-td">29.44</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="google-visualization-table-tr-even">
                    <tr class="google-visualization-table-tr-odd">
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think you can use `closest` and `nth-child` together as `closest` traverses the DOM tree upwards. Are you trying to change the background color of the first `td` in those rows?

Comment: yes i am trying to change the color of 1st TD, and i am creating DOM dynamically

Comment: Also, you have a `tr` class of "google-visualization-table-tr-head". You should look at using the `thead` element instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Replacing this

```
 $(this).closest('td:nth-child(1)').css("background-color", "red");
```

with this

```
$(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').css("background-color", "red");
```

Comment: Yes, this is working, i will mark this as true as this was the 1st answer that worked for me

Answer (score 3):

Using [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) your are:

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the
>   selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its
>   ancestors in the DOM tree.

but the aren't any elements up in the DOM with that selector; you are seaching a child element so use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched
>   elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

Code:

```
$(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').css("background-color", "red");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/YE5nr/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $('#chart3 .google-visualization-table-tr-odd > td:first-child, 
  #chart3 .google-visualization-table-tr-even > td:first-child')
 .css('background-color', 'red');
```